# Sync Little Big Planet 3 between multiple PS4 systems?

Tags: psn, little-big-planet-3

If I start playing LBP3 on one PS4 with my PSN user, then I install the game onto another PS4 with the same PSN user, will my LBP3 progress, items, etc automatically transfer? Does the LBP3 servers remember what I've collected or would I need to manually copy/transfer the save file from the first PS4?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not happen automatically. At least, I don't believe that LBP3 behaves differently from many (most/all?) other PS4 games in this way.

You have a couple of options to make this easy-ish, but none of which will be fully automatic:

- If you have PS+, you can have a single PS4 act as primary and upload your saves to the cloud automatically. *However* even while logged in as the same user, consecutive systems don't get this benefit and you must manually download your saves before you begin to play, and upload them for you primary to access when you are finished.
- Keep your game/saves on an external drive (now that there is support for this), and transfer the whole drive between systems.
- If you do not have PS+ or do not want to use the methods above, you can always backup your save files to USB drives and copy them onto the system you happen to be using at the moment. Instructions for how to do this can be found on [playstation.com](https://www.playstation.com/en-ie/get-help/help-library/system---hardware/storage---data/manage-ps4-saved-game-data-in-system-storage/).

  1. Connect a USB storage device to the PS4 system.
  2. Go to  [Settings] > [Application Saved Data Management] > [Saved Data in System Storage] > [Copy to USB Storage Device].
  3. Select a game (LBP3 in this case).
  4. Place ticks next to the data you wish to copy, or [Select All], and select [Copy].

*Some disclaimers*:

- I have never had a 2nd PS4 connected to my PS+ account to act as a non-primary, but there are tons of "success stories" of this online.
- I have never used an external drive for this purpose, but in theory it should work. Here's a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4Pro/comments/674g8p/ps4_external_hard_drive_transfer_to_ps4_pro/) of someone using this method to move save data between a PS4 and PS4 Pro.